# Input value changes after clicking in another div with Jquery mask and vue

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, mask

I'm trying to use the jquery mask and vue plugin, my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="mb-2">
    <label class="form-label">Salary</label>
        <input v-model="newEmployeeSalary" class="form-control moneyMask" id="employeeSalary" required>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('.money').mask('000.000.000.000.000,00', {reverse: true});
});
```

The problem is that the inputed value changes after clicking in another div.
Example :

Here I'm adding a money value, and the mask works perfectly:

[image: The value is 2.000,0]

Then, here I just clicked on the next input of the form and the Salary input mask breaks:

[image: Values chagnes]

My vue code:

```
data() {
    return {
      newContractTotalValue: '',
    }
},
```

I noticed that if I remove the v-model the error dissapers, but I need to use it.
Can someone help me with that ?, I really have no idea what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$('#employeeSalary').mask('000.000.000.000.000,00', { reverse: true });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.